# Azure Databricks - Failed to find data source: couldFiles

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new to autoLoader and trying to run below autoLoader code in notebook.

```
spark.readStream.format("couldFiles")\
  .option("cloudFiles.format","csv")\
  .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/test*.csv") \
  .writeStream
```

But got below error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: couldFiles. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Can anyone please help advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: couldFiles.**

The above error happening because of `cloudFiles`.Configure cloudFiles accordingly as shown in the below code:

```
cloudFiles ={
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId" :"<subscription_Id>",
    "cloudFiles.connectionString" :"<connectionString_Storage_account>",
    "cloudFiles.format":"csv",
    "cloudFiles.tenantId":"<tenantId>",
    "cloudFiles.clientId":"<client_ID>",
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret":"<Client_Secret>",
    "cloudFiles.resourceGroup":"<Resource_group_name>",
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications":"yes"
}
```

For more information Configuring **Auto Loader** in Azure Databricks follow this [**link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNG-5uRY4o8), it has a detailed explanation about read and write **streaming data** on the **Azure Databricks**.